# Select top 2 distinct for each id and date

Tags: sql-server, distinct, partition

I have a table like this :

Table1:

```
  [Id]        [TDate]     [Score]
    1         1.1.00       50
    1         1.1.00       60
    2         1.1.01       50
    2         1.1.01       70
    2         1.3.01       40
    3         1.1.00       80
    3         1.1.00       30
    3         1.2.00       40
```

My desired output should be like this:

```
[ID]  [TDate]    [Score]
1         1.1.00       60
2         1.1.01       70
2         1.3.01       40
3         1.1.00       80
3         1.2.00       40
```

So fare, I have written this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 Id, TDate, Score
FROM
(   SELECT Id, TDate, Score, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by TDate order by Score) Od
    FROM Table1
) A
WHERE A.Od = 1
ORDER BY Score
```

But it gives me :

```
[ID]  [TDate]    [Score]
2         1.1.01       70
3         1.1.00       80
```

of course I can do this:

```
"select top 2 ...where ID = 1"
```

and then:

```
 union 
`"Select top 2 ... where ID = 2"`
```

etc..
but I have a 100,000 of this..

Any way to generalize it to any Id? 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the output.  Why not two rows for id = 1?

Comment: I think he wants the max(score) for each ID and TDate combination

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't make sense.  Let me assume you want two rows per id.  Then the query would look like:

```
SELECT TOP 2 Id, TDate, Score
FROM (SELECT Id, TDate, Score,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by Score DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Table1
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 2
ORDER BY Score;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that you want two rows per `id`.  Hence, `id` is in the `PARTITION BY`.
- The `WHERE` now selects two rows per group in the `PARTITION BY`.
- There is no need for `SELECT DISTINCT` in the outer query -- at least for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TOPTWO AS (
    SELECT Id, TDate, Score, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY TDate 
        order by SCORE
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM [table_name]
)
SELECT * FROM TOPTWO WHERE RowNo <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something this can be done with a simple group by

First I prepare a temp table for testing :

```
declare @table table (ID int, TDate varchar(10), Score int)
insert into @Table values(1, '1.1.00', 50)
insert into @Table values(1, '1.1.00', 60)
insert into @Table values(2, '1.1.01', 50)
insert into @Table values(2, '1.1.01', 70)
insert into @Table values(2, '1.3.01', 40)
insert into @Table values(3, '1.1.00', 80)
insert into @Table values(3, '1.1.00', 30)
insert into @Table values(3, '1.2.00', 40)
```

Now lets do a select on this table

```
select ID, TDate, max(Score) as Score
from   @table
group by ID, TDate
order by ID, TDate
```

The result is this :

```
ID  TDate   Score   
1   1.1.00  60  
2   1.1.01  70  
2   1.3.01  40  
3   1.1.00  80  
3   1.2.00  40
```

So all you need to do is change @table to your table name and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Make partition by ID and TDate and sort by score in descending order

```
 ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID,TDate order by Score DESC) Od
```

Complete script

```
WITH CTE AS(

    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID,TDate order by Score DESC) RN
    FROM TableName
 ) 
 SELECT *
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE RN = 1
```